# pywinauto for uia application, for minimized window showing element not found error

Tags: pywinauto, uia

When we connect to a UIA backend window using pywinauto, getting element not found error.

Below is the code I have tried. When executing the uia backend application, and if the application is minimized I am getting the below element notfound error. Meantime if the application is running in background window with out minimized, everything works fine!!!

```
'''This part of code only for the testing purpose'''
    app = pywinauto.Application(backend="uia")
    app.connect(path="C:\xyz\Exe\Service\abc.exe")
    window = app.window_(title=u'abc')
    if window.is_minimized():
        window.restore()
    window.wait('ready', timeout=10)
    # window.print_control_identifiers()
    button = window.child_window(title="Ramping settings...")
    button.click()

    print("END-->Exec")



  Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Projects/TestAutomation/TBricks/Interface/UI/TBrickUIApp.py", line 124, in <module>
    if window.is_minimized():
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pywinauto\application.py", line 367, in __getattribute__
    ctrls = self.__resolve_control(self.criteria)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pywinauto\application.py", line 248, in __resolve_control
    raise e.original_exception
pywinauto.findwindows.ElementNotFoundError: {'process': 7108, 'backend': u'uia', 'title': u'PPHSControl'}
```

Answer (score 1):

i understand that it is a mistake / parameter missed when i created the window handle.

```
window = app.window_(title=u'PPHS', visible_only=False).restore()
```

Above code will restore if minimized.